# How to click on element returned by querySelectorAll Javascript in Applescript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, applescript

I am trying to get this code snippet to work, the classname specified exists, and if I run in the Automator nothing happens.

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
        execute front window's active tab javascript "document.querySelectorAll('[class=\"gvConversationList-item\"]')[0].click()"
end tell
```

Comment: why are you using an attribute selector to select an element by class? `document.querySelector('.gvConversationList-item')`

Comment: Why firing a click does not work really depends on what the element is and what is listening to the event. Hard to guess.